# Não retorna o valor da variável

Tags: php

Coloquei o código no paste bin: http://pastebin.com/vG6BSpuu

```
   foreach ($linhas as $novalinha){
    $novoTituloSlug = get_string_between($novalinha, 'id="', '">');
    echo $novoTituloSlug;
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas .  "<link>http://localhost/site/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";
```

No `echo $novoTituloSlug;` 
tenho o resultado: `valor1valor2valor3`.

Mas na linha debaixo não imprime o valor, se eu colocar echo tenho o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO).

Segue o código completo:

```php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " " . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini+= strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

// Lê conteúdo do txt
$documento = file_get_contents($arquivo);
$linhas = explode("<ul", $documento);
$novalinhas = "";
$novoPostId = 100;
foreach($linhas as $novalinha)
{
    $novoTitulo = "TÍTULO I";
    $novaData = date(DATE_RFC822);
    $novaData2 = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $novoTituloSlug = get_string_between($novalinha, 'id="', '">');
    echo $novoTituloSlug;
    $novaCategoria = "constituicao-da-republica-federativa-do-brasil-de-1988";
    $novoTituloCategoria = "CONSTITUIÇÃO DA REPÚBLICA FEDERATIVA DO BRASIL DE 1988";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<item>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<title>" . $novoTitulo . "</title>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<link>http://localhost/votanalei/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<pubDate>" . $novaData . "</pubDate>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<dc:creator><![CDATA[ale]]></dc:creator>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<guid isPermaLink='false'>http://localhost/votanalei/?p=" . $novoPostId . "</guid>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<description></description>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<content:encoded><![CDATA[<ul" . $novalinha . "]]></content:encoded>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_id>" . $novoPostId . "</wp:post_id>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_date>" . $novaData2 . "</wp:post_date>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_date_gmt>" . $novaData2 . "</wp:post_date_gmt>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_name>" . $novoTituloSlug . "</wp:post_name>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:status>publish</wp:status>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_password></wp:post_password>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<category domain='category' nicename='" . $novaCategoria . "'><![CDATA[" . $novoTituloCategoria . "]]></category>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<category domain='post_tag' nicename='" . $novaCategoria . "'><![CDATA[" . $novoTituloCategoria . "]]></category>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:postmeta>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "</wp:postmeta>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "</item>" . "\r\n";
    $novoPostId = $novoPostId + 5;
}

$file = fopen("test.txt", "w");
$results = fwrite($file, $novalinhas);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Se possível, poste o código completo para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: Utilize `var_dump($novoTituloSlug);` para conferir o que tem na variável.

Comment: retorna  - artigo1

string 'artigo1' (length=7)

artigo2

string 'artigo2' (length=7)

artigo3

string 'artigo3' (length=7)

Comment: O var_dump mostra: string 'artigo1' (length=7)

Comment: Em qual linha acusa o erro? Na que está o `echo`? Tirando o `echo` ela funciona normalmente?

Comment: O erro é que não imprime na linha do link, e se eu coloco echo, aparece este erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: nesta linha:         $novalinhas = $novalinhas .  "<link>http://localhost/votanalei/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";

Comment: Porque você usa aqui "novalinha" `$novoTituloSlug = get_string_between($novalinha, 'id="', '">');` e aqui `$novalinhas = $novalinhas .  "<item>" . "\r\n";` "novalinhas"?

Comment: Porque eu queria concatenar, as linhas.
No foreach, ele varre por array, e vai concatenando nas novalinhas.

Comment: Veja se voce nao esqueceu de terminar a linha anterior com ponto e virgula ';'

Comment: Não esqueci não, estranho né? os valores das datas, são impressos sem problemas, mas, tenho uma string que funciona com echo, mas, não imprime quando concateno com uma variável

Comment: @AlêMoraes Qual o erro que você está recebendo agora? uma forma alternativa de concatenar string é usando `.=`, veja um [exemplo aqui](http://pastebin.com/i1GKsemA).

Comment: O erro é que não imprime na linha do link, e se eu coloco echo, aparece este erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO). 
Coloquei o código neste link: http://pastebin.com/vG6BSpuu

Comment: @AlêMoraes Era porque você estava colocando o `echo ..` numa variável, veja se é isso: [**exemplo**](http://ideone.com/gTBFXT).

Comment: Nãp é isso, pois, mesmo tirando a linha 79 e 80 do seu exemplo, e tirando o "s" do final da variavel na linha 84, não dá erro, mas também, não imprime a variável na linha 84, nem a pau, kkk

Comment: Na função se tiro o conteúdo e coloco apenas return "teste";, dai funciona, ele imprime o valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código funciona.

```
function get_string_between(){
    return 'teste';
}

$linhas = array(1,2,3,4,6,7);

$novalinhas = '';

foreach ($linhas as $novalinha){
    $novoTituloSlug = get_string_between($novalinha, 'id="', '">');
    echo $novoTituloSlug;
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas .  "<link>http://localhost/site/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";
    echo $novalinhas;
}
```

[**<kbd>Demo →</kbd>**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/459009a17f4a5af6c7d618269baba8ad4e52227a)

O que acredito que esta acontecendo, é que no seu arquivo local, você esqueceu de digitar um ponto e virgula `;` ou alguma coisa do tipo, segue um exemplo de código com o erro que você informou.

```
function get_string_between(){
    return 'teste';
}

$linhas = array(1,2,3,4,6,7);

$novalinhas = '';

foreach ($linhas as $novalinha){
    $novoTituloSlug = get_string_between($novalinha, 'id="', '">');
    echo $novoTituloSlug;
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas .  "<link>http://localhost/site/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n"
    echo $novalinhas;
}
```

[**<kbd>Demo →</kbd>**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/950bb0ae604f9b248dc047be2650de1771c14f55)

Código completo funcionando:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    return 'teste';
}

$linhas = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$novalinhas = "";
$novoPostId = 100;
foreach($linhas as $novalinha)
{
    $novoTitulo = "TÍTULO I";
    $novaData = date(DATE_RFC822);
    $novaData2 = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $novoTituloSlug = get_string_between($novalinha, 'id="', '">');
    echo $novoTituloSlug;
    $novaCategoria = "constituicao-da-republica-federativa-do-brasil-de-1988";
    $novoTituloCategoria = "CONSTITUIÇÃO DA REPÚBLICA FEDERATIVA DO BRASIL DE 1988";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<item>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<title>" . $novoTitulo . "</title>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<link>http://localhost/votanalei/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<pubDate>" . $novaData . "</pubDate>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<dc:creator><![CDATA[ale]]></dc:creator>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<guid isPermaLink='false'>http://localhost/votanalei/?p=" . $novoPostId . "</guid>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<description></description>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<content:encoded><![CDATA[<ul" . $novalinha . "]]></content:encoded>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_id>" . $novoPostId . "</wp:post_id>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_date>" . $novaData2 . "</wp:post_date>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_date_gmt>" . $novaData2 . "</wp:post_date_gmt>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_name>" . $novoTituloSlug . "</wp:post_name>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:status>publish</wp:status>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:post_password></wp:post_password>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<category domain='category' nicename='" . $novaCategoria . "'><![CDATA[" . $novoTituloCategoria . "]]></category>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<category domain='post_tag' nicename='" . $novaCategoria . "'><![CDATA[" . $novoTituloCategoria . "]]></category>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:postmeta>" . "\r\n";
        $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>" . "\r\n";
        $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "</wp:postmeta>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "</item>" . "\r\n";
    $novoPostId = $novoPostId + 5;
    echo $novalinhas;
}
```

[**<kbd>Demo →</kbd>**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/006e8bbd685bc0e5abab005e1235145880f660d9)

Comment: Vlw Édipo, pelo que vi o problema está nesta função, mas, estranho funcionar o `echo $novoTituloSlug;` e não funcionar o `    $novalinhas = $novalinhas . "<link>http://localhost/votanalei/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";`

Comment: esta sobrando um `;` nesse código que você postou.

Comment: Eu coloquei todo o código aqui  http://pastebin.com/vG6BSpuu

Comment: Nesse código eu utilizo 3 vezes o $novoTituloSlug, no primeiro testo com echo e funciona, nos dois seguintes não funciona e mostra o erro Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Na função se tiro o conteúdo e coloco apenas return "teste";, dai funciona, ele imprime o valor.

Comment: Nesse caso, o problema esta no `$linhas = explode("<ul", $documento);`, o primeiro item do array é uma string vazia, quando você faz os explodes dentro da função `quebra`, você esta fazendo encima  de uma string vazia.